# I need to overlap two .txt files eliminating the common lines

Tags: awk

I have 2 sets of data, I need to overlap them to get the final list of needed runs

I have tried `grep` and `awk 'NR==FNR{...}!a[$0]'` but that does not give me a right output

```
grep -vf goodruns.txt idontneed.txt
```

and

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}!a[$0]'
```

input: goodruns.txt with a list of numbers:

```
09987
09989
09991
09995
09996
```

idontneed.txt with a list of numbers:

```
09987
09988
09991
09993
09995
09997
```

desired output:

```
09989
09997
```

Comment: why is your desired output not: `09989 09996` ?

Comment: Also, properly formatting your question will help a lot.

Comment: I think your `grep` is on the right track, but you want `idontneed.txt` to be the argument to the `-f` option, so try reversing the order of files on the cmd line. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a list of lines that exist in `goodruns.txt` and that don't exist in `idontneed.txt`, this is exactly what `comm` is for.

A solution with bash, sort and comm might be:

```
comm -2 -3 <(sort goodruns.txt) <(sort idontneed.txt)
```

If you prefer to use awk or grep, they will work fine if you just reverse the files:

```
grep -vf idontneed.txt goodruns.txt

awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}!a[$0]' idontneed.txt goodruns.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear to me, but assuming: a) you only want lines from the first file that aren't in the second file, and b) your expected output is wrong because 09997 doesn't appear in `goodruns.txt` and it should be 09996, which does:

```
$ join -v1 goodruns.txt idontneed.txt
09989
09996
```

This does require that your files are sorted, which your samples are.

Comment: fair, I made a mistake in the output. Now that works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `awk` works fine, just make sure you have `idontneed` first

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next} !a[$0]' idontneed.txt goodruns.txt
09989
09996
```